# Gnome-Terminal won't run on VNC

Tags: gnome-terminal, 22.04, vnc

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with VNC for remote desktop purpose. Recently, the terminal won't open in the VNC session. However, this behavior is only observable on one user account and the terminal in VS Code is working fine.

If I insist on opening terminal, it will have some round waiting process animation on the [top left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTflv.png) and then the VNC session will crash.

Here is the cat of /var/log/syslog https://pastebin.com/kJ2wvFRn. For convenience, I would like to highlight this part

```
Non UTF-8 locale (ANSI_X3.4-1968) is not supported!
```

This is the probable error cause but I don't know how to fix it. My cat /etc/default/locale is

```
cat /etc/default/locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

As a comparison, here is my cat /var/log/syslog from a successful terminal run at VNC session (https://pastebin.com/ZkY09mfZ). I would guess it a dbus problem.

Here is my xstartup setting. I am using tigervncserver.

```
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-setting-daemon & gnome-session & gnome-terminal
```

I installed other terminal from apt (currently using guake) and it run fine.

Comment: Have the permissions changed on the shell file for the user? They would need execute permissions.

Comment: @Frankie0p I checked my ls -al /bin/gnome-terminal and it seems the chmod is 3400. I don't know if this the valid one.

Comment: Have you read this [thread](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1879048#c2)?

Comment: @Frankie0p yap, already tested that. I already done sudo locale-gen  but it still wont' work. FYI, my error is the same (Non UTF-8 locale (ANSI_X3.4-1968) is not supported!)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out the root problem. While locales.conf is correct. My env has an LC_ALL override. export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 solved my problem.

So, after checking your locales-gen, don't forget to check your env!

Comment: You can click on the 'check' or 'tick' mark to accept your own answer...